# Post request from Vue application blocked by CORS policy

Tags: c#, rest, vue.js, cors

I'm trying to call my C# web-api from my Vue webapplication but I encounter the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://www.api.example.com/' 
from origin 'http://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The following code snippet shows how I'm calling the rest-api with use of `axios`.

```js
import axios from 'axios'

const client = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://www.api.example.com',
    json: true,
    withCredentials: true
})

export default {
    async execute(method, resource, data) {
        return client({
            method,
            url: resource,
            data,
            headers: {}
        }).then(req => {
            return req
        })
    },

    myFunc(data) {
        return this.execute('post', '/', data)
    }
}
```

The web-api with the POST request method is as follows:

```cs
[EnableCors("VueCorsPolicy")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<int> Post([FromBody] Data data)
   {
       // stuff
   }
}
```

I have also added a CORS to my "ConfigureServices" method in the Startup.cs file.

```cs
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("VueCorsPolicy", builder =>
    {
       builder
       .WithOrigins("http://www.example.com")
       .AllowAnyHeader()
       .AllowAnyMethod()
       .AllowCredentials();
    });
});
```

And lastly I have also added to the "Configure" method in the Startup.cs file:

```cs
app.UseCors("VueCorsPolicy");
```

Answer (score 1):

**CORS** is a security mechanism, that cannot be overcome by simply modifying your code. The server has to be set so that it allows the requests from your source - so, if you control the server you can do it.

However, there are some solutions that help you during development phase, like `cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com`.

You should add it before the `baseURL` in your code, like this:

`baseURL: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.api.example.com'`.

This is NOT a solution for production, only for development.

You can host your own `cors-anywhere` app, more on this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere

Comment: it is extremely insecure to use as a proxy for a problem of **your own API**, it is definitely recommended to go to modify the backend, this answer (IMHO) is deviant, please delete it

Comment: `.WithOrigins("http://www.thomasleoblok.dk/")` this is where your problem is, it should be `.WithOrigins("http://www.example.com")` since it is http://www.example.com you want to allow to make requests, it you want to allow any site you can change it to `.WithOrigins("*")`

Answer (score 1):

`.WithOrigins("http://www.thomasleoblok.dk/")` this is where your problem is, it should be `.WithOrigins("http://www.example.com")` since it is example.com you want to allow to make requests, it you want to allow any site you can change it to `.WithOrigins("*")`

Comment: First I tried to change the specific url but sadly it didn't work. Then I tried to change it to `.WithOrigins("*")` but I still get the same error.

Comment: when `.WithOrigins("*")`, you do not include this `.AllowCredentials()` since The  setting origins to "*" (all origins) is invalid if the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header is present. read more from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: which version of asp .net core are you using @Thomas Leo Blok

Comment: I use .net core 3.1

Comment: The last time i used asp .net core was when it was 2.2, let me check 3.1 docs to see

Comment: also make sure you call `app.UseCors('VueCorsPolicy')' before any
   `app.UseAuthorization(); or
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
             {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });`

Comment: I call the `app.UseCors("VueCorsPolicy");` as the first thing in the "Cofigure" method.

Comment: [EnableCors("VueCorsPolicy")] remove this from the controller from the docks  > Different policies can be applied to controllers, page models, or action methods with the [EnableCors] attribute. When the [EnableCors] attribute is applied to a controller, page model, or action method, and CORS is enabled in middleware, both policies are applied. We recommend against combining policies. Use the [EnableCors] attribute or middleware, not both in the same app.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying locally you must open the origin localhost, otherwise the BE will always return a cors error as **localhost** != http://www.thomasleoblok.dk/

for testing I suggest you enable **AllowAnyOrigin()**
example:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("VueCorsPolicy", builder =>
    {
       builder
       .AllowAnyOrigin()
       .AllowAnyHeader()
       .AllowAnyMethod()
       .AllowCredentials();
    });
});
```